# Vuex mock store undefined in Jest unit test

Tags: vue.js, jestjs, vuex

I'm new to jest and am trying to write a unit test that relies on the value of a store property.

I tried to create a new mock store in my test (I already have a mock store for a different test), but for some reason, I keep getting the error

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'state' of undefined
```

My tests are:

```js
import { shallowMount, createLocalVue,} from '@vue/test-utils';
import userButtons from '@components/user-profile/UserButtons.vue';
import Vuex from 'vuex';
import { defaultValues, } from '@store/api/userButtons.js';

const localVue = createLocalVue();
localVue.use(Vuex);

describe('UserButtons', () => {
    let actions; 
    let store;
    let storeIsAdded;
    
    beforeEach(() => {
    actions = {
        getUserInfo: jest.fn(),
    };
    store = new Vuex.Store({
        modules: {
        userButtons: {
            namespaced: true,
            actions,
            state: {
            userButton: defaultValues,
            },
            mutations: {
            setUserButton: jest.fn(),
            },
        },
        },
    });
    storeIsAdded = new Vuex.Store({
        state: {
        isItemAdded: true,
        },
    });
    });
    test('vuex called on create', () => {
    shallowMount(UserButtons, { store, localVue, propsData: { id: 3406304, }, });
    expect(actions.getUserInfo).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });

    test('renders correctly', () => {
    const wrapper = shallowMount(UserButtons, { store, localVue, propsData: { id: 3406304, }, });
    expect(wrapper.element).toMatchSnapshot();
    });

    test('indicates remove if isItemAdded is true', () => {
    const wrapper = shallowMount(UserButtons, { storeIsAdded, localVue, propsData: { id: 3406304, }, });
    expect(wrapper.find('.button-action.my-items').text()).toBe('- Remove from My Items');
    });
});
```

The first two tests, which just use `defaultValues` for my store, pass.

The last test, `'indicates remove if` isItemAdded`is true, is the one that fails, and is using the mock store,`storeIsAdded`.

If anyone has any insight, it would be much appreciated!!!

EDIT:

Even if I modify my mock store to be more similar to the store that seems to be working, like this:

```js
storeIsInList = new Vuex.Store({
    modules: {
    userButton: {
        namespaced: true,
        actions,
        state: {
        userButton: {
            isItemAdded: true,
        },
        },
    },
    },
});
```

I get the same error.

Comment: This might help https://lmiller1990.github.io/vue-testing-handbook/vuex-in-components.html#using-createlocalvue-to-test-store-state

Comment: the EDIT version has a spelling error at modules.userButton. Is it supposed to be modules.userButtons?

Answer (score 0):

It seems the error is when accessing the store state in the component. So, my guess is that the store maybe need to be module/namespace, i.e.

```
storeIsInList = new Vuex.Store({
  modules: {
    userButtons: {
      namespaced: true,
      actions,
      state: {
        userButton: {
          isItemAdded: true,
        },
      },
    },
  },
});
```

And as @il0v3d0g stated, maybe the namespace name is wrong.